# target is not called even after updating dependency

Tags: makefile, dependencies

In the following code, I expect when `app/outputs.list` is updates, the related scripts run and when when it is not touched from the last make, the scripts are not called. At the end, the compiler must be called.

However, even if I edit the `app/outputs.list`, the scripts are not called in any way. Where did I make mistake?

Makefile:

```
SOURCES := main.cpp
OUTDIR:= ./out
BINDIR:= ./bin
OBJDIR:= ./bin/obj
OBJECTS := $(addprefix $(OBJDIR)/,$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o))
DEPFILES:= $(OBJECTS:.o=.d)
VARLISTS:= app/outputs.list

CXX := g++
CXXFLAGS := -c -g -MD -MP
LIBS:= -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system 

.PHONY: all

# default
all: $(VARLISTS) $(BINDIR)/sim
    @echo "done"

app/outputs.list:
    bash ./scripts/outputs.bash
    bash ./scripts/sim_outputs.bash

$(BINDIR)/sim: $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) $^ -o $@ $(LIBS)

$(OBJDIR)/%.o: %.cpp
    @if [ ! -d "$(OBJDIR)" ]; then mkdir -p $(OBJDIR) && echo "$(OBJDIR) directory created: $(OBJDIR)";  fi
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -MF $(OBJDIR)/$*.d -o $@  $<

-include $(DEPFILES)
```

This is the output:

```
$ make
./bin/obj directory created: ./bin/obj
g++ -c -g -MD -MP -MF ./bin/obj/main.d -o bin/obj/main.o  main.cpp
g++  bin/obj/main.o -o bin/sim -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system 
done
```

However the scripts have an `echo` to prove they have been called:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "outputs called"
```

Seems they are not called.

The `app/outputs.list` file contains a list of variables and the scripts are supposed to generate appropriate arrays in an auto-generated `.hpp` file.

Comment: What targets are supposed to depend on the `app/outputs.list` file?

Comment: @EtanReisner `app/outputs.list` contains a list of variable names and script generate appropriate `.hpp` files according to the list. I have updated my post. do you have any suggestion?

Comment: You missed the point. What targets are supposed to have that file as a prerequisite task such that they should be re-run if it changes? Right now the only target that does that is `all` (as indicated in my answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only target that depends on `$(VARLISTS)` is `all`. So the only target that is going to be run because the `app/outputs.list` file changes is the `all` target. But the `all` target is also `.PHONY` so it is always going to run, no matter what.

The general format of a make rule is:

```
output-file: input-file
    commands to generate output-file from input-file
```

So in this case the output files are the generated header files and the input file is the `apps/output.list` file. So the rules should like something like this:

```
sim_outputs.hpp: app/outputs.list
    bash ./scripts/sim_outputs.bash

outputs.hpp: app/outputs.list
    bash ./scripts/outputs.bash
```

Which should cover the rebuilding cases. The initial (clean slate) build might not work that simply because the header files aren't going to be listed as prerequisites of anything anywhere (the `.d` files haven't been created yet) so there might need to be a bootstrapping step added for that.

Comment: you believe that it will always run. and what I have experienced says that it does not run. I like to find the source of this disagreement. When scrips  have run two new `.hpp` files are updated. They are in the list of prerequisites since the `-include $(DEPFILES)` uses the autogenerated `.d` file. Those `.hpp` files are included in my program and they must automatically be added in the list of prerequisites. Is it exactly what you indicated in the comment?

Comment: The files in `DEPFILES` are `.d` files not `.hpp` files so that `-include` directive is meaningless here. No, I said the `all` target will always be run. The `app/outputs.list` target will only ever run **once** because it has no prerequisites so the file will always be up-to-date as far as make is concerned. Delete the `app/outputs.list` file and it will run again the next time you run `make` or `make all` but then never run again. You need to give it prerequisites or mark it `.PHONY` (or better use a force rule, see the manual). But that's only part of your ultimate issue.

Comment: But if I mark it as `.PHONY` it will always run. Is there any way to run `app/outputs.list` target only when this file is updated from the last time of running `make`?

Comment: The target for that file updates that file. You just asked if there is a way to run the target when the target was previously run. You need to figure out what *other* changes need to trigger that target to run and what *other* targets (if any) depend on that file (as opposed to depending on the relevant `.hpp` files).

Comment: I am a bit confused. I guess maybe we are talking about two different thing. Or maybe I am catching your words properly.

`The target for that file updates that file.`

Do you mean each time I update `app/outputs.list` the scripts are called?

`You just asked if there is a way to run the target when the target was previously run.`

I thinks better to add the condition that the target has been previously run but the file updated too.

`You need to figure out what other changes need to trigger that target to run`

I think there is no other change.

Comment: A target `file.txt: ; ./some_script` tells make to run `some_script` whenever it needs to update `file.txt`. So your `app/outputs.list: ; bash ./scripts/outputs.bash; bash ./scripts/sim_outputs.bash` target says to make "Whenever you feel that you have a reason to need to generate/update the `app/outputs.list` file you should run these two scripts." But you haven't told make what conditions should trigger that since it has no prerequisites. So make only runs those scripts to generate that file **once** and then never again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73714/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-ar2015).